# Local Diffeomorphism from $D_R$ to ${C}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, diffeomorphism

I am trying to find a function that maps a disk of arbitrary radius $R$ to the complex plane. I have found that the function
$$f(z)= \frac{z}{R}\frac{1}{1-|z/R|}$$
appears to do this precisely, however the magnitude on the bottom is causing me some difficulty in the problem I am attempting to solve. Ideally the $f(z)$ should be a diffeomorphism in the real sense! I was wondering if such a function $f(z)$ exists, but instead of considering $|z/R|$ on the denominator, we instead have $|z/R|^2$ such that the square root vanishes? [Wikipeidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk) proposes that the function
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{1-|z|^2}$$
is a bijective, real analytic function of the unit disk to the complex plane with analytic inverse. However I am not convinced with this since the inverse of this function is
$$f^{-1}(z)=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{4z^2+1}}{2z}$$
which is multivalued for some values of $z$.

Comment: You did not calculate $f^{-1}(z)$ correctly.

Comment: Hi @MartinR. If possible, may you please be able to provide some further details? Wouldn't the inverse of this function be solving $w=f(w)$ here?

Comment: Hi @AnneBauval unfortunately not. I am wondering where my error is in confirming what is claimed on Wikipedia where they say $f(z)=\frac{x+iy}{1-x^2-y^2}$ is invertible. I am struggling to find the inverse

Comment: Martin told you your error was in calculating $f^{-1}$ (by the method given in the duplicate, I find $f^{-1}(z)=zg(2|z|^2)$ where $g(t):=\frac{\sqrt{1+2t}-1}t$) and the duplicate gives another diffeo.

Comment: @AnneBauval How did you arrive at this inverse? It is not super clear to me. It appears to be similar to the inverse that I have obtained.

Comment: You want to solve $w = z/(1-|z|^2)$ for $z$. First solve $|w| = |z|/(1-|z|^2)$ for $|z|$, then $z = (1-|z|^2)w$.

Comment: Like in the duplicate: to solve $z'=f(z)$, first solve $r'=\frac r{1-r^2}$( for $r,r'\ge0$). Then $z=r\frac{z'}{r'}.$